# (Win7) Automatically configure display options with laptop & external monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

First off, this is on windows 7.

I use an external monitor with my laptop. Sometimes I use both, sometimes I just use one or the other.

**What I want it do to:**

- Laptop lid **open** + External monitor **on**: Displays are 'extended' so I have two screens.
- Laptop lid **open** + External monitor **off**: All windows from the external move onto my laptop screen. The second screen is no longer accessible.
- Laptop lid **closed** + External monitor **on**: All windows from my laptop move onto my external screen. The second screen is no longer accessible.

**What it currently does:**

- Laptop lid **open** + External monitor **on**: Displays are 'extended' so I have two screens.
- Laptop lid **open** + External monitor **off**: All windows from the external move onto my laptop screen. The second screen is no longer accessible.
- Laptop lid **closed** + External monitor **on**: All windows from my laptop **stay** on my laptop screen. The second screen is still accessible, although completely unusable.

I've been getting around this by switching between 'Extend these displays' and 'Duplicate these displays' in the screen resolution settings... But I'm hoping there's a way to automatically solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: A short-cut key would be Win+P.